# Couldn't resolve resource @style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode.Inverse

Tags: android, rendering, android-resources, android-appcompat, android-actionmode

I'm creating an Android app in Android Studio. When I open the layout editor, I see that gray "popup window" on top of the layout, which says that it

> Couldn't resolve resource @style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode.Inverse.

This happens when I change the "rendering version" to *API 15* (*Android 4.0.3*).
It worked a minute ago, but when I switched back to the layout, I just got this error.

**Edit:** I use the `AppCompat` library.
The theme is defined like this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />
```

The app works fine when I run it, but doesn't render correctly (at least it's giving me the error) in the editor.

I would be glad if someone could help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the `appcompat` library?

Comment: @ZiadAkiki Yes, I do. See the updated question.

Comment: here is the issue http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=163572  in my case it's not taking android:gravity="left" for Device running API 14 !!! surprisingly android:gravity="left|right" works!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This problem occured to me when updating Android Studio to version 1.1.0 and opening an old project without changing anything.

For me only changing the preview's rendering API to 19 or above makes the message disappear.

Comment: Exactly! It did start appearing when I updated Android Studio. It works by changing the render version. I've already tried that. I was thinking of a way to download/find the missing resources or something alike, but I'll mark this as correct. Thanks!

Comment: This seem more like a workaround, not a real solution!

Answer (score 10):

Hey I faced the same problem and the solution that i figured out was - In android studio **Open** the **Select Theme** Dialog and under the **All** category select `NoTitleBar.OverlayActionModes` and press okay.
The problem would be solved. But it can show up into a dark theme.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for me, however, the preview doesn't really matter. I just use it to position the components, then try the rest on my phone. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Your welcome.! It worked for my app though. But yea it doesn't matter if its working on your device.

Answer (score 0):

Make you project API Level newer.
For me,the problem occured when my `build.gradle` content like this:

```
compileSdkVersion 16
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xiaoguang.xx"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 16
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

After i download the sdk 19 and change `build.gradle`, the problem was fixed.

```
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xiaoguang.xx"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

[change preview'api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo1VD.png)

Comment: This "fixes" the problem by making your project not work with SDK version 16.